# Data-Attributes and Script Injection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, xss, javascript-injection

For my rails application I use data-attributes rather extensively, as it was easy and the site was never expected to be finished or published, simply something I did for personal fun. A short example of the raw HTML would be

```
<span class="player-name" data-id="4" >Example Player</span>
```

I then could access the 'id' in coffeescript in the following way:

```
id = $('.player-name').data('id')
```

I was wondering if this utilization of data-attributes could potentially make the site susceptible to attacks through people editing the data-attribute in their developer console.  Also if there is a better approach to accessing data in jQuery I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Any data coming from the client side should be validated on the server side. With that caveat in mind, data provided via data attributes is no different than a user supplied value that is passed to the server as far as security is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. People can modify this. But this is hardly unique to `data-` attributes; people can modify *anything* and send *any* request with *any* parameters to your server.

You should *always* validate data coming from clients. Always, always, always. Too often have I seen applications where I have an url such as `http://example.com/orders/42` where modifying the `42` to `666` resulted in me viewing a stranger's order. Oops! With AJAX requests it takes a bit more effort to fake data, but not much. People can (and will!) modify anything on your client-side: URLs, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, etc. so it's *always* wrong to rely on that for security.

In practice, this means that after getting an object from the database in your Rails app you should *always* check if the currently logged in user is allowed to view this object. For example, in a controller you might do something along the lines of:

```
def show
    # Fetch it from the DB
    some_object = SomeObject.find params[:id]

    # Make sure the current user is authorized!
    raise if some_object.player_id != logged_in_player.id

    # ..your controller code..
end
```

I don't necessarily recommend you do this "manually" like in the above example. For Ruby on Rails there are two well-known gems to help with this:

- [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit); this is what I would recommend. It's simple, elegant, and flexible.
- [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan); also used a lot. It's more complicated than Pundit and I've found it doesn't actually provide more features. Your mileage may vary, though.